# Не могу решить зависимости apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Устанавливаю `gimp`

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Но получаю вот такое сообщение:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.8.16) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.16-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (>= 2.8.16) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.8.16-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libbabl-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.10) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 remarkable : Depends: python3-markdown but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gir1.2-webkit-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: wkhtmltopdf but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Перед установкой, разумеется, сделал `update`. Пробовал указанные пакеты устанавливать руками. Но оказывается, что они зависят друг от друга. Например, `gir1.2-webkit-3.0` и `python3-markdown` зависят друг от друга, о чём информирует `apt`.

Запуск `apt-get` с флагом `-f` не помог.

Запуск команды: `tail -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}; lsb_release -a`:

```
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution. deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team. deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atareao-ubuntu-telegram-xenial.list <== deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list <==
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost. deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/longsleep-ubuntu-golang-backports-xenial.list <== deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/longsleep/golang-backports/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/longsleep/golang-backports/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mmk2410-ubuntu-intellij-idea-community-xenial.list <== deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mmk2410/intellij-idea/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mmk2410/intellij-idea/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mystic-mirage-ubuntu-pycharm-xenial.list <== deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list <== deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-ubuntu-make-xenial.list <== deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/voldyman-ubuntu-markmywords-xenial.list <== deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/voldyman/markmywords/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/voldyman/markmywords/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list <== deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID:    Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial
```

Comment: Пара вопросов: 1. какая версия Ubuntu 2. Пробовали дать команду sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод `$ tail -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}; lsb_release -a`

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов 16.04. Пробовал.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin сделал

Comment: попробуйте `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf это историю я не хочу делать. Как-то раз сделал `sudo apt-get upgrade`, после чего система упала. Причин я не выяснил. Но `upgrade` я делаю только в случае крайней необходимости.

Comment: @hedgehogues хм... а я каждый день по расписанию делаю `autoremove`, `clean`, `update`, `dist-upgrade` и никогда никаких проблем не возникало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так у вас никаких репозиториев не указано — вот ничего и не находится.

судя по упоминаниям в `/etc/apt/sources.list`, стоит у вас версия *xenial*.

добавьте хотя бы такую строку в этот файл:

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

и обновите список пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

а потом уже можете ставить нужные пакеты.

Comment: Где взять другие зеркала? Сколько их нужно добавить?

Comment: 1. [зеркала](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). 2. нисколько.

Comment: Как это нисколько? Хотя бы одна должна же быть? По крайней мере это следует непосредственно из Вашего ответа.

Comment: о! прошу прощения. при копировании не удалил строку `-src`. исправил ответ.

Comment: зеркала добавлять точно не надо. а вот другие репозитории — возможно и нужно. но это уже совсем другая история. у вас-то не было **вообще** ни одного репозитория.

Comment: Окей, спасибо .

Comment: На самом деле, в тот раз, я не стал впиливать пакет, который Вы указали, поскольку решил проблему на тот момент. Сейчас обнаружил, что пакеты, по-прежнему не ставятся.